# Excel VBA: copy table as a single column

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet that looks like this

```
data1 data2 data3 ... data10
 ...   ...   ...  ...  ...
dataX dataY dataZ ... dataN
```

I need to somhow "flatten" the data into one single column like this:

```
data1
data2
data3
 ...
data10
dataX
dataY
dataZ
 ...
dataN
```

I tried creating a macro that would automate a copy+paste process starting from a selection. Here's my code:

```
Sub copyIn1Col()
'
' copyIn1Col Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+r
'
    Selection.copy
    Range("B31").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("D3:D13").Select
End Sub
```

The problem with that is that it overwrites the copied selection to the same range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most simplest and fastest would be to use arrays. I am assuming the following

1. The data is in Sheet1 from range `A1` to `E15`
2. You want the output in Sheet2 Cell `A1`

Hope this is what you want?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim inPutR, outPut()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, n As Long

    '~~> Change this to the respective range
    inPutR = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:E15")

    ReDim Preserve outPut(UBound(inPutR, 1) * UBound(inPutR, 2))

    For i = LBound(inPutR, 1) To UBound(inPutR, 1)
        For j = LBound(inPutR, 2) To UBound(inPutR, 2)
            outPut(n) = inPutR(i, j)
            n = n + 1
        Next j
    Next i

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Resize(UBound(outPut) + 1) = _
    Application.Transpose(outPut)
End Sub
```

Comment: Siddharth I' m surprised at you, putting a `redim` inside a (double) loop. Especially when the size of `output` can be calculated fron the bounds of `inputr`.

Comment: Yeah You are right... LOL :) Guess it is one of those days :)

Comment: Is there a way to make the range defined by inPutR dymanic, something like this: `Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select`

Comment: +1 for variant array. Only difference is I never use LBound from a sheet as it is implicitly 1

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sub I use that I've modified to do what you're looking for.  It dumps the contents in a sheet called "Data", change that to be whatever sheet you want it to add it to.

```
Sub Transform()

Dim rows As Long
Dim cols As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim c As Long
Dim t As Long

t = 1
rows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.rows.Count
cols = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For r = 1 To rows 'If you have headers change 1 to the first row number of data
    For c = 1 To cols

        Sheets("Data").Cells(t, 1) = ActiveSheet.Cells(r, c).Value

        t = t + 1
    Next c
Next r


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 :) However I would not recommend using `UsedRange` You might end up with lot of blank values. For example your data maybe in `A1:E15` and the `UsedRange` is from `A1:Z200` :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout true that, a bit of lazy code.  I could add a blank check for this purpose.